# Using Events over the LAN with SuperClassic?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I have an application that uses Events from the server to do some processing. Everything worked fine while the firebird **superserver** was running on the same machine, but now, I had to move firebird on a multicore machine so I used **SuperClassic**. The application that waits for the events runs on another machine on the same LAN. Is there any way to use the events in this way?

I'm using Firebird 2.5, 64bits, SuperClassic.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events works the same way in Superserver x SuperClassic x Classic. I recommend you to edit firebird.conf and uncomment the line with the parameter RemoteAuxPort, and set it to a port that you are sure is not being used by another application, and is open in your firewall.

PS: You also should know that, unfortunately, the events implementation in FB is weak, so you cannot trust it 100%.

Comment: I used RemoteAuxPort and I disabled windows firewall on both machines (they are behind a firewall box) and now the events work fine.